# pass value to label inside UITabController from another tab iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uitabview

I have `UITabController` with labels and buttons inside. I need to pass `textView` value from one `tab` to another's `label`. Using segues.

Simply I need to do like this code:

```
In TAB1:
 textView1 = @"test";
 set Tab2.label1 = textView1;
```

Thanks,
David.

Comment: please provide some more information....

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/